# ac load control using a microcontroller via relay

Tags: microcontroller

when i switching ac induction motor  by micro controller via a relay it some times hanging up or restart the controller while I'm using optical couple r for isolation between 12v supply of relay and 5v supply of micro-controller. I'm trying to use large capacitors on supply but in vain

Comment: You probably need a snubber network across the relay contacts.

Comment: Do you have a transistor at the  uController Output? You need sufficient current to energize the coil. BC54x would do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if possible, it would be great to have some sort of isolated circuit to determine when the AC is at around 0 volts (zero crossing) and switch the relay at that point. This would certainly extend the life of your relay and reduce the chances of getting a large electromagnetic pulse from the motor, which may induce spurious signals in the traces (if it's nearby) or the wiring to your microcontroller board. A Snubber is a good idea as stated. Does the problem still occur if you disconnect the motor and just operate the relay?
If so it may be switching spikes from the relay coil itself. Make sure you have some capacitance near the relay to dampen that, and also if possible don't use the same ground plane on your circuit board, for the relay and the microcontroller. Run a separate trace for the relay ground to the power input connector. You may also want to put a diode (e.g. 1N4007 or similar) across the relay coil (reverse biased) to help kill spikes.